# Creating new list or card in Trello using RESTful

Tags: trello

I'm not able to create a list or a card using the RESTful API of Trello. I have tried using the following:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/lists/list-id/cards?idBoard=4fe20acefbbd331f0502ea21&name=API-CARD&key=my-app-key&token=read-write-token
```

The result was a GET response with this list cards.

How can I create a list or a card using the RESTful API?

Comment: What do you mean by “The result was a GET response with this list cards.”? More exactly, by “this list cards”.

Comment: Meaning, the result was a list of cards under the requested list. While the result I expected was creation of new card nder that list.

Comment: Did you try doing a `POST`?

Comment: How do I do that? Isn't the above URL is POST?

Answer (score 3):

1. A HTTP request consists of a 'method' + URL + [optional body]

   > typical HTTP methods used in RESTful API's are GET, POST, PUT and DELETE.
2. In the case of creation of a card this could be done through:

   ```
   method = POST
   URL    = https://api.trello.com/1/lists/{LIST_ID}/cards?name={CARD_NAME}&desc{CARD_DESC}&key={APP_KEY}&token={APP_TOKEN}"
   ```
3. Such a request to could be accomplished in the following bash script:

   ```
   OUTPUT=output.html
   LIST_ID=....the list id... # eg: 4051e76b61c12f3162444628
   CARD_NAME=foo
   CARD_DESC=boo
   APP_KEY=...key obtained for you application earlier....
   APP_TOKEN=...token obtained for you application earlier....
   TMP=`mktemp --tmpdir=.`

   echo -n > $TMP

   wget -O $OUTPUT \
        --debug \
        --no-check-certificate \
        --post-file="$TMP" \
        -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1" \
        https://api.trello.com/1/lists/${LIST_ID}/cards?name=${CARD_NAME}&desc${CARD_DESC}&key=${APP_KEY}&token=${APP_TOKEN}"
   ```

I have not tried this out, but hope this helps.